# Index was outside the bounds of the array how to resolve

Tags: c#, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a code. When i execute the code i am getting an error. here is my code given below

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  Session.RemoveAll();
  DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
  string[] strArray = new string[4];
  int num1 = checked (Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Split(Conversions.ToString(today), "/", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)[4]) - 4);
  DropDownList ddlYear = _ddlYear;
  ddlYear.Items.Clear();
  int num2 = (int) checked ((short) num1);
  short num3 = checked ((short) (num1 + 6));
  for (short index = (short) num2; (int) index <= (int) num3; ++index)
    ddlYear.Items.Add(Conversions.ToString((int) index));
  ddlYear.DataBind();
  ddlYear.SelectedValue = Conversions.ToString((int) Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Year));
  LoadDept();
  Session.Add("rno", (object) 0);
  Session["rno"] = (object) new Random().Next();
  Rno = Conversions.ToInteger(Session["rno"]);
}
```

Comment: use debugger and find out which line cause the exception

Comment: Please add some more information. What error occurs, which line causes the exception,...

Comment: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. on this line  int num1 = checked (Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Split(Conversions.ToString(today), "/", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)[4]) - 4);

Comment: What is it that you are trying to get from the date string? The `DateTime` structures has properties for getting all components of a date, so I'm sure that there are better ways of doing that.

Comment: compiler does not go to for loop. error occur before enter into for loop

Comment: Please, let me understand, are you doing all this code just to get the value of the next 6 years from the current year in a dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0):

check your split value of the line:

```
int num1 = checked (Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Split(Conversions.ToString(today), "/", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)[4]) - 4);
```

It is quite obvious by the exception message that the split did not return more than 5 items ( no 4 index)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** Check for the 2nd reason which is probably the reason in your example

**First check :**
How are you sure that the Strings.Split will give a 5 (or more) length array ?
In order to avoid this IndexOutOfRangeException you should format your date in a way your date is always formatted in a 5 (or more) length array splitted with a "/".
But even if the date is well formatted, you should always, recover the array in a var, check if the size corresponds to what you wish and THEN only recover a hardcoded value :

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  Session.RemoveAll();
  DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
  string[] strArray = Strings.Split(Conversions.ToString(today), "/", -1, CompareMethod.Binary);
  if(strArray.Length >= 5)
  {
      int num1 = checked (Convert.ToInt32(strArray[4]) - 4);
      DropDownList ddlYear = _ddlYear;
      ddlYear.Items.Clear();
      int num2 = (int) checked ((short) num1);
      short num3 = checked ((short) (num1 + 6));
      for (short index = (short) num2; (int) index <= (int) num3; ++index)
        ddlYear.Items.Add(Conversions.ToString((int) index));
      ddlYear.DataBind();
      ddlYear.SelectedValue = Conversions.ToString((int) Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Year));
      LoadDept();
      Session.Add("rno", (object) 0);
      Session["rno"] = (object) new Random().Next();
      Rno = Conversions.ToInteger(Session["rno"]);
  }
}
```

**Second check :**
The other reason you may have this error, is probably due to the fact you did not understood what number the first occurence of an array is.
The answer is `0`. So if you wish to get the 4th value, you need to enter `3` :

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  Session.RemoveAll();
  DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
  string[] strArray = Strings.Split(Conversions.ToString(today), "/", -1, CompareMethod.Binary);
  if(strArray.Length >= 4)
  {
      int num1 = checked (Convert.ToInt32(strArray[3]) - 4);
      DropDownList ddlYear = _ddlYear;
      ddlYear.Items.Clear();
      int num2 = (int) checked ((short) num1);
      short num3 = checked ((short) (num1 + 6));
      for (short index = (short) num2; (int) index <= (int) num3; ++index)
        ddlYear.Items.Add(Conversions.ToString((int) index));
      ddlYear.DataBind();
      ddlYear.SelectedValue = Conversions.ToString((int) Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Year));
      LoadDept();
      Session.Add("rno", (object) 0);
      Session["rno"] = (object) new Random().Next();
      Rno = Conversions.ToInteger(Session["rno"]);
  }
}
```

**Third check :**
Why do you specifically use [Strings.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is a VisualBasic method).
Better use a [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).
By the way, DateTime objects already have formatting methods like [DateTime.ToLongDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring.aspx) :

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  Session.RemoveAll();
  DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
  string[] strArray = today.ToLongDateString().Split("/".ToCharArray());
  if(strArray.Length >= 4)
  {
      int num1 = checked (Convert.ToInt32(strArray[3]) - 4);
      DropDownList ddlYear = _ddlYear;
      ddlYear.Items.Clear();
      int num2 = (int) checked ((short) num1);
      short num3 = checked ((short) (num1 + 6));
      for (short index = (short) num2; (int) index <= (int) num3; ++index)
        ddlYear.Items.Add(Conversions.ToString((int) index));
      ddlYear.DataBind();
      ddlYear.SelectedValue = Conversions.ToString((int) Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Year));
      LoadDept();
      Session.Add("rno", (object) 0);
      Session["rno"] = (object) new Random().Next();
      Rno = Conversions.ToInteger(Session["rno"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your index from *4*

```
Strings.Split(Conversions.ToString(today), "/", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)[4]
```

to **a lower value** (example: *3*)

```
Strings.Split(Conversions.ToString(today), "/", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)[3]
```

Your `string.Split()` method returns probably less than 5 items (probably 3, because of the `DateTime` and the split on */*). Because `C#` starts counting from **0**, the fourth element, for example, has an index of **3**.

Comment: What is the length of `strings.split` (I guess 3..)?

Comment: How to check the length of strings.split

Comment: @user3514929 `Strings.Split(Conversions.ToString(today), "/", -1, CompareMethod.Binary).Length`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could replace your code with

```
 int curYear = DateTime.Today.Year;
 int endYear = curYear + 6;
 for (int x = curYear; x <= endYear; x++)
    ddlYear.Items.Add(x.ToString());
```

No splitting required from a string created by converting a date.
Just use the `Year` property and a simple loop.

You could also remove the loop with:

```
 var range = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Today.Year, 6)
 ddlYear.Items.AddRange(range.Select(x => new ListItem(x.ToString())).ToArray());
```